# Poorly Rendered Font in Webpage

Tags: html, css, fonts, baseline, skel

My businesses website was originally built on a Skel framework, using the Baseline template. As a result there is a lot of CSS/SCSS that was bundled in.

When building the site we used the Arimo font, linked here:

https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Arimo

This is how the text looked on the Skel site:

[image]

But, for a few reasons which have little relevance, we decided to build the site from scratch and move away from Skel and Baseline.

We are using the same font and general design, but when I attempted to use the same font the rendering is very, very different.

[image]

There is no CSS that I can find in my code that would indicate any changes to the rendering, any help?

Comment: Looks like a simple sizing issue. Check which CSS is *applied* according to the browser (firefox or chrome -> dev tools -> style) and then check whether your new site applies. Find the differences, and fix them?

Comment: Also check the weights. Did the site originally (or, does it now) use uncommon weights like `font-weight:300`?

Comment: It's neither of these things, as I've said the CSS rules applied are identical, it must be something else

Comment: they are most certainly not identical: you wouldn't get both larger headings, but also smaller paragraph text. So: instead of making us guess, prove you're right by putting evidence for it in your post. What's the full CSS readout for the elements, for both the old and new site? And have you put those in a dedicated file for testing? What was the result of that?

Comment: I'll post the site tomorrow, and provide links, from there you can investigate. If you believe that the CSS isn't identical, I won't dispute that, as I'm simply searching for the solution to my problem, but as far as I can investigate, the CSS is identical.